# Trying to write a code for translating input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code to translate an inputted message, but my output comes out blank. I thought I typed it all out correctly, and far as I can tell, I did.

This is what I typed out:

```
#First, create a dictionary for the pirate language

piratelanguage = {
    'hello':'ahoy',
    'excuse me':'arrr',
    'sir':'matey',
    'boy':'matey',
    'man':'matey',
    'madam':'proud beauty',
    'officer':'foul blaggart',
    'the':'th',
    'my':'me',
    'your':'yer',
    'is':'be',
    'restroom':'head',
    'restaurant':'galley',
    'hotel':'fleabag inn',
    'coins':'doubloons',
    'pirate':'buccaneer',
    'friend':'mate',
    'you':'ye'
}

#Next, get a message from the user

message = input("Enter a message: ")

#Then translate the message into the pirate language

piratemessage = " "

for i in range(len(message)):
    if message[i].upper() in piratelanguage:
        piratemessage = piratemessage + piratelanguage[message[i].upper()]
        piratemessage = piratemessage + " "
    
#Now to print out the pirate message

print(piratemessage)
```

And this is my output:
Enter a message: Hello, madam, would you direct me to the nearest hotel?

It outputs the input message just fine, but there's just a blank line underneath it where the translated message should be. Thoughts?

Comment: Try `lower()` instead of `upper()`. And you need to split the message at the spaces: `message = message.split(' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question code, `message[i]` refers to a single character, and `.upper()` should be `.lower()`.  You would need to iterate over the individual words of the message, but a simple `.split()` won't handle punctuation properly.

Instead, use a regular expression to match phrases using word breaks and iterate over the replacements.  Then it can handle punctuation:

```
import re
piratelanguage = {
    'hello':'ahoy',
    'excuse me':'arrr',
    'sir':'matey',
    'boy':'matey',
    'man':'matey',
    'madam':'proud beauty',
    'officer':'foul blaggart',
    'the':'th',
    'my':'me',
    'your':'yer',
    'is':'be',
    'restroom':'head',
    'restaurant':'galley',
    'hotel':'fleabag inn',
    'coins':'doubloons',
    'pirate':'buccaneer',
    'friend':'mate',
    'you':'ye'
}
message = input("Enter a message: ").lower()
for key,value in piratelanguage.items():
    message = re.sub(r'\b' + key + r'\b',value,message)
print(message)
```

Gives:

```
Enter a message: Hello, madam, would you direct me to the nearest hotel?
ahoy, proud beauty, would ye direct me to th nearest fleabag inn?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input comes in as a string so you need to split it on spaces to get the individual words, e.g.

```
message = input(...).split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. All the keys in your pirate language dict are lowercase, but you call `upper()` on each word when you compare. You need to use `lower()` instead, so the case matches.
2. You are splitting up the input by character, so if the input were to be `excuse me, sir`, you would want to check if `excuse me` and `sir` are in the dictionary, but this code would check if `e`,`x`,`c`,...,`r` were in the dictionary. The solution here is not so simple as splitting on the spaces in the input, since there could be punctuation and `excuse me` has a space in it.

Comment: I changed it to lower() and put in the message=input().split(" ") . Ran the program with the same input and the output was: ye th . Ran it again without punctuation marks, and I got this as the output: ahoy proud beauty ye th fleabag inn. So lower seemed to partially fix it, what would you do rather than splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
piratelanguage = {
    'hello':'ahoy',
    'excuse me':'arrr',
    'sir':'matey',
    'boy':'matey',
    'man':'matey',
    'madam':'proud beauty',
    'officer':'foul blaggart',
    'the':'th',
    'my':'me',
    'your':'yer',
    'is':'be',
    'restroom':'head',
    'restaurant':'galley',
    'hotel':'fleabag inn',
    'coins':'doubloons',
    'pirate':'buccaneer',
    'friend':'mate',
    'you':'ye'
}



message = input("Enter a message: ")

piratemessage = ""

for i in message.split(): #split message to iterate on each word
    new_word = i.lower()
    temp_word = ('').join([s for s in new_word if s.isalnum()])
    if temp_word in piratelanguage.keys(): # if word is in pirate language
        new_word = new_word.replace(temp_word, piratelanguage[temp_word])
    piratemessage += new_word + ' '
print(piratemessage.capitalize())
```